# about mysql index Why can't I add indexes to all fields

Tags: mysql

For the MySQL index book, adding indexes to ordinary fields will give up the back table operation, which will reduce IO and improve performance. Why can't we add indexes to all fields? Is it to increase the insertion speed

Comment: Yes it slightly increases the insertion speed

Comment: *Is it to increase the insertion speed* NO. In general (almost in all cases) the index presence decreases insertion speed, because server must update both the table body and each index chain.

Comment: *Why can't we add indexes to all fields?* Each table copy used in a query may in general use only one of all existed indices for improving the query, all another are ballast which cannot increase the query speed (but may decrease during data change). Moreover, in most cases a composite index is more effective than the index by one separate column. The amount of all possible indices, including all composite variations, may be too high, and the most part of them will be used never. In general - only the most suitable indices which improves the most critical queries are created.

Comment: In this way, I will reduce the number of times I want to cover the I / O fields